# Data in oracle DB has trailing spaces but they're being stripped by sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm retrieving data from an oracle database using sqlplus.

The command is something like this:

```
select property_name||'|'||property_value from some_table where x = 'foo'
```

and the data in the database definitely has trailing spaces (this is a thing which causes problems in an application I work with).

When I retrieve that data the spaces have been automatically trimmed somehow. I can see them when I use SQLDeveloper and when retrieved by the application directly.

Is there a way I can stop this happening?

Comment: Is this a spooled file? Do you have set trimspool on?

Comment: No, trimspool is off. I'm wondering what would even happen to a line of data which itself had a linebreak in it. Would the linebreak be escaped, quoted, or mess up the data returned by adding an empty line?

Comment: @AmbroseChapel Adding an empty line can cause problems depending on which character you use.  If you only use CHR(13), on some programs on some platforms (such as SQL*Plus on Windows), it will reset the cursor to the beginning of a line and will overwrite characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be working.

```
SQL> create table spaces (blanks varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into spaces values ('A');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into spaces values ('A     ');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into spaces values ('A  ');

1 row created.

SQL> Insert into SPACES (BLANKS) values ('A   

B   ');

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.


SQL> select blanks, length(blanks), blanks || '!' from spaces;

BLANKS               LENGTH(BLANKS) BLANKS||'!'
-------------------- -------------- ---------------------
A                    1               A!
A                    6               A    !
A                    3               A  !
A                    9               A
B                                    B  !

SQL>
```

The last column shows that none of the 'blanks' are being trimmed. Can you share your scenario in your question details? Or try what I've demonstrated and compare.

Comment: If I add the ` || '!' `to put the exclamation point after it, it works the way I see above. But if it's not concatenated with something on the right, the spaces aren't there.